# Looping through the array and replacing certain numbers with the string in JS

Tags: javascript, loops

everyone! I'm trying to figure out why my code isn't working here..
The task is to loop the array and replace certain numbers with the string.

```
  let integers = [];
for (i in integers){
    if (integers[i] == 4) {
        integers[i] = 'Fish';
    }
    else if (integers[i] == 7) {
        integers[i] = 'Cat';
    }
}
```

Comment: Because the array is empty

Comment: No, it has values, prompted as random, in total 50. I just simplified the code...Everything works except for this chunk.

Comment: `for in` loop is used to loop through the properties of an *object*. If you have an *array*, you need to loop with a `for` loop or a `forEach` (or maybe a `map`, in your specific case). If you can provide a full example, I am sure you will find some help

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, as CertainPerformance said, you never seem add anything to the array `integers`.

Secondly, your syntax is incorrect. In JS, to make a `for` loop you write

```
for (let i=0; i<integers.length; i++){ ... }
```

Instead of

```
for (i in integers){ ... }
```

Comment: and what is the content of `i` in the first?

Comment: edited - `i` goes from 0 to the maximum index of `integers`.